# PHP Parse Error when uploaded to server

Tags: php, parse-error

It works fine in localhost, but when I upload, it shows `Parse Error`. Can you figure out my error?

My PHP Function:

```
function all_fuel_info(){
global $conx;
$sql = "SELECT `qty`,`cost`,`rate` FROM `fuel_order`;";
$query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
$liters = 0; $cost = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $liters += $row["qty"];
    $cost += $row["cost"];
}
$info = array('qty' => $liters, 'cost' => $cost);
return $info;
```

}

Then the PHP Code:

```
  $total = all_fuel_info()["cost"];
```

Is this not supported in PHP? According to my knowledge yet, I can point to that item of the array using the index. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax isn't supported until PHP 5.4.  Your server is likely running an older version.

Comment: Thank you but Is there a solution for Lower versions of PHP? Current Server Version is 5.3.27.

Comment: @TikaDattaPahadi Yes, assign the return value of `all_fuel_info()` to a variable and then access it normally.  `$something = all_fuel_info(); $total = $something['cost'];`

Comment: Do you mean?
  $total = all_fuel_info();
  $total = $total["cost"];

Comment: I get the same error: [22-Apr-2014 03:24:15 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/myliveca/public_html/akitech/go/vims/fr_reports/all.php on line 12

Comment: @TikaDattaPahadi It works fine.  If you're getting an error, show your updated code.